# Load data in background mode using background worker in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I am using query from a SQLite database as the AutocompleteCustomSource for a ComboBox. Also, I want to load data in separate thread.  My LoadData method works fine when called directly, but it fails when it is called from the BackgroundWorker thread.  When it is called from the background thread, it throws a **`Specified cast is not valid`** exception on the `csearch.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add(hh("Taj"))` line.  Below is my code:

```
Sub LoadData()

        Dim connetionString As String
        Dim cnn As SQLiteConnection
        connetionString = "Data Source=" + Application.StartupPath + "\Mydatabase.db;"
        cnn = New SQLiteConnection(connetionString)
        cnn.Open()
        Dim sqlComm88 As New SQLiteCommand("SELECT Taj FROM Taj_deu ", cnn)
        Dim hh As SQLiteDataReader = sqlComm88.ExecuteReader()
        While hh.Read()
            csearch.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add(hh("Taj"))
        End While

    End Sub



Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork

        Call loaddata()

    End Sub



 Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()

    End Sub
```

Comment: Try changing it to `hh("Taj").ToString`

Comment: Are you saying that this does not fail if you call `LoadData` directly rather than through a background worker?

Comment: Yes, exactly! It loads data normally but it freezes the form until it loads all the data. I want it to load data and at the same time user could use the application normally.

Comment: It's odd that it would get that casting error, but the problem may be that you are accessing the combobox from the worker thread.  You are never supposed to access controls or forms from another thread.  You need to do all UI work on the UI thread.  The typical way to do that is to use the form or control's Invoke method.

Comment: Exactly! You are right. I have tried this and solved the problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I added it as an answer instead of a comment.  Do you mind marking it as the correct answer so it will be more helpful to future people having this problem?

Comment: Of course bro.. I will do this now! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

We'd need to know which line it failed on, but at a glance, try using ampersands instead of plus signs to concatenate your strings in VB.

```
connetionString = "Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\Mydatabase.db;"
```

Comment: It Fails here:  csearch.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add(hh("Taj"))

Comment: Thank you very much for fast reply But I have tried this. Error remains the same.

Comment: What is the value of hh("Taj") here?

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
 csearch.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add(hh("Taj"))
```

To:

```
 csearch.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add(hh("Taj").ToString())
```

Comment: Thanks for such fast replies guys. But I did all this stufs but error remains the same :(

Comment: Try adding `Option Strict On` to the top of your file and see if that gives you any more useful messages.

Comment: Did you recompile after adding the `Option Strict On`?  It should fail to compile with that turned on.

Comment: Yes, nothing interesting occurred. I got bunch of other errors bro.. Did you look on screenshot?

Comment: The screenshot you linked to appears to show a message that is shown by the debugger while the process is running.  It doesn't show compiler errors.

Answer (score 0):

It's odd that it would get that casting error, but the problem is that you are accessing the property of the ComboBox from the worker thread. You are never supposed to access controls or forms from another thread. You need to do all UI work on the UI thread. The typical way to do that is to use the form or control's `Invoke` method.

Answer (score -1):

Yes use the ampersands instead of the plus. VB.net does not interpret the + as concatenation(the plus is used in C based languages). If this does not sort out your error use a 'try catch' block around your code for testing. See below for an example.

Add a break point over the catch. Use a watch to inspect all the information regarding the error.

Comment: The plus sign does concatenate in VB.NET and is perfectly safe, and in my mind, preferable, provided you are using `Option Strict On`.  The ampersand was necessary in VB6, but in .NET it's a bit of a hack for backwards compatibility to VB6 syntax.  It circumvents the standard operator overloading functionality that .NET provides.

Comment: I have no problems with plus sign but I have problem with 'backgroundworker'. My come works fine when I just call 'LoadData()' OnFormLoad or onClick event. I have to run this sub via 'BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()'